# Функция jQuery при неактивности мышки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Можно ли как-нибудь заставить запускаться функцию, если пользователь 5 секунд не двигает мышкой? Есть скрытый div с анимацией, необходимо чтобы он появлялся не сразу при загрузки страницы, или не просто через 5 секунд, а именно когда курсор мышки 5 секунд стоит на месте.

При этом, если он двигает мышкой, то таймер скидывается и начинает считать только когда снова курсор замер.

Comment: Конечно же можно! :)

Comment: Как вариант сделать таймер и при активности грызуна обнулять его + проверку на таймера, как только перевалит за пороговое значение показать дивник. Сам ничего подобного не делал так, что на чистой фантазии выдал.

Comment: Да ты и сам всё знаещь :) За чем глупые вопросы задаёшь?

Comment: zenith, не нервничай

Comment: @new_user_1 Спокоен как слон. Мраморный

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#hideDiv').hide(); // прячим необходимый див

var showDiv = function(){
     $('#hideDiv').show();
}; // функция для его отображения, будет стоять на таймере

var timeOut = setTimeout(showDiv, 3000); // ожидание показывания дива

$('body').mousemove(function(){
     clearTimeout(timeOut); //  если дёрнули мышкой обнулили ожидание
      $('#hideDiv').hide(); // спрятали див
     timeOut = setTimeout(showDiv, 3000); // начали ждать снова
});
```

[пруф.](http://jsfiddle.net/LeFBg/1/)

**UPD:** [апдейт](http://jsfiddle.net/LeFBg/2/) от тов. [@neoascetic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/4022/neoascetic)

Comment: [Это демо](http://jsfiddle.net/LeFBg/2/) получше, с более "высоким" `body`

Answer (score 3):

```
function showHidenBlock(){
  this.timeout = null;
  this.showBlock = function(){
    $('#myHidenBlock').show();
  };
  this.resetTimeout = function(){
    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(this.showBlock, 5000);
  }
}
var showHidenBlock = new showHidenBlock();
$(window).on({
  mousemove:function(){showHidenBlock.resetTimeout()}
});
```

Как вариант решения. Но в следующий раз желательно точнее задавать вопрос :)

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь есть удобный jquery плагин для твоей цели: [jquery-idletimer-plugin](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/)

[ДЕМО](http://paulirish.com/demo/idle-timer)